# Creating webhooks or listening events from shopify POS

Tags: node.js, express, shopify, shopify-app

I am developing a loyalty app or Shopify POS system. I want to listen to the events such as cart creation or Updation or customer creation etc on the POS system and work accordingly. I have created some webhooks which are working only through the online shop but not from POS.

I have searched a lot but didn't find a way to make them work through POS.

I am creating my app using nodeJs and expressJs.

This is my current code of accepting the hooks which are working only from the online shop.

```
app.post('/getproduct', (req,res) => {
    // alert("skfjfjn");
    res.status(200).send('OK');
    console.log("nagesh test ")
    console.log(req)

  });
```

This image is my webhook on admin.

[image: webhook on admin]

Comment: You cannot receive Webhook on cart creation in POS system.
Explain your workflow we are already running our application in POS but we don't need POS cart webhook.

Comment: It's sorted now! Thanks anyway.